# Raspberry Pi 3b+ Fake KMS not listed

Tags: video, chromium, gpu

I've been trying to follow tutorials on enabling hardware accelerated video decoding for my Raspberry Pi 3b+, such as this one:

https://lemariva.com/blog/2020/08/raspberry-pi-4-video-acceleration-decode-chromium

They all seem to want me to select a GL Driver called "Fake KMS", but even after installing the various packages mentioned, it's not listed for me.

I'm using the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS, with updates installed.

- `cat /proc/device-tree/soc/firmwarekms@7e600000/status` returns `disabled`
- `cat /proc/device-tree/soc/v3d@7ec00000/status` returns `okay`
- `chrome://gpu` shows `Video Decode: Software only: Hardware acceleration disbled`

How can I make this option avaiable, or otherwise do what is needed to enable GPU video decoding in chromium?

[image: Image of raspi-config with Fake KMS missing as an option]

Comment: I assume that link points to instructions for older release of Pi OS - if you have the latest (bullseye) release - then you should have `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` in your `config.txt`

Comment: @Bravo I did this and restarted, and it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: So, which version of Raspberry Pi OS do you have installed?

Comment: @Bravo 11 (bullseye)

Comment: oh, and you're reading a video acceleration page for pi4 but you don't have a pi4